Why are rapid adjustments applied to the radiative forcing?
The change in the top of atmosphere radiative flux is $\Delta N = \Delta F + \alpha \Delta T$ (from IPCC AR6 Chapter 7.1). Here $\Delta F$ is radiative forcing, $\alpha$ is a feedback parameter, and $\Delta T$ is the change in global surface air temperature (GSAT).
From my understanding, a given radiative forcing $\Delta F$ creates an imbalance $\Delta N > 0$ that leads to the warming of the atmosphere + surface system. Eventually, a new equilibrium is reached $\Delta N = 0$, in the process leading to a change in GSAT that depends on the feedback parameter $\alpha$.
However, the $\Delta F$ used in the AR6 is the effective radiative forcing (ERF) that accounts for "rapid" adjustments to the stratosphere and troposphere. Why are these adjustments necessary?
I have read some papers mentioned in the AR6 Ch 7, however this question still bothers me. Is it simply because the initial forcing can lead to changes in the atmosphere (without changing GSAT) that indirectly change the value of the forcing $\Delta F$? If so, is the ERF a better input to $\Delta N = \Delta F + \alpha \Delta T$ to predict $\Delta T$?
Edit (partial answer):
After reading through several papers here is what I have learned.
GSAT is an average of the sea surface temperature (SST), and the land surface temperature (LST). In using $\Delta N = \Delta F + \alpha \Delta T$ we are interested in the value of $\Delta T$ resulting from a forcing $\Delta F$. Note that $\Delta F$ can be a change in aerosol, a change in land use, a change in radiative flux (due to a greenhouse gas), etc... Here I assume $\Delta F$ is a change in radiative flux due to the introduction of a greenhouse gas.
An instantaneous radiative forcing (IRF) is not suitable to use as the value for $\Delta F$ as the predicted change in GSAT $\Delta T$ is not accurate. This is because quantities in the atmosphere, independently of the GSAT and in addition to the IRF, can change and affect the radiative flux. For example, the stratosphere can heat up due to the presence of a greenhouse gas and increase the amount of downward flux towards the troposphere surface system. Since the stratospheric temperature is not tied to the GSAT, it independently 'adjusts' the overall radiative forcing.
In short, there are many such adjustments (stratospheric and tropospheric) that result from the forcing agent, e.g a greenhouse gas, and not from the change in GSAT $\Delta T$.
Note that a feedback is a change in a quantity caused by the GSAT. For example, a change in GSAT can lead to a change in sea ice which can change surface albedo.
Feedbacks are accounted for in the feedback parameter $\alpha$.
Adjustments are not explicitly accounted for, however, using the ERF instead of the IRF for $\Delta F$ does account for adjustments. ERF = IRF + adjustments
Overall, adjustments are needed to better estimate the change in GSAT.
